# Есть ли способ оптимизировать множественную выборку из текстуры в шейдере?

Tags: алгоритм, opengl, glsl, шейдеры, gles2.0

для сглаживания я использую шейдер который несколько раз выбирает значение из текстуры
при этом сильно падает фпс.

Есть ли способ оптимизировать множественную выборку из текстуры в шейдере?

Или может есть более продвинутые способы сглаживания?

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D Texture;
uniform vec3 u_settingsmooth;

varying vec2 v_UV;

void main() {
    //параметры экрана
    float x = u_settingsmooth.x;
    float y = u_settingsmooth.y;
    //смешивание
    gl_FragColor = (
        texture2D(Texture, v_UV) +
        texture2D(Texture, vec2(v_UV.x + x, v_UV.y + y)) +
        texture2D(Texture, vec2(v_UV.x + x, v_UV.y + y * 2.0)) +
        texture2D(Texture, vec2(v_UV.x + x, v_UV.y + y * 3.0))
    ) * 0.25;

}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать перенести вычисление текстурных координат в вершинный шейдер. т.е. чтобы в пиксельный шейдер на вход подавались 4 готовые координаты. Помимо ускорения собственно вычисления координат, это должно способствовать улучшению выборки семплера, который очень страдает, если координаты становятся известны только в последний момент.

Comment: интересный подход, можно попробовать

Comment: А можете проиллюстрировать откуда вы сэмплите и что получаете в итоге? Есть еще пара стратегий, но они не ко всем случаям подходят.

Comment: @Kromster Применяю его для размытия грубых кромок при создании теней, ssao, пострендере и других эффектах. Брал в примерах по opengl.

Comment: У меня похожие сценарии. Тогда рассмотрите еще: подставлять непосредственное значение  u_settingsmooth при сборке шейдера (сделать константой). Вообще все что можете выносите в контанты и если надо для подгонки - перестраивайте шейдер на лету - это норм; если монотонно сэмплите из текстуры, то сэмплите между 2 или 4 текселей и получите бесплатное усреднение из них;